# Is there an Emacs command for delete-to-char?

Tags: emacs

In Vim, I can combine delete and search:

```
df[char]
```

to delete to (and include the char)

```
dt[char]
```

to delete to (excluding the char).

In Emacs:

```
M-z : zap-to-char
```

is equivalent to `df[]` in vim.

Is there a command for deleting to a char?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**zap-up-to-char** is defined in misc.el (not loaded by default), so you can add this to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'misc)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'zap-up-to-char)
```

Apparently the behavior of M-z was changed from zap-up-to-char to zap-to-char sometime in Emacs 19 (early 90's). Some more discussion: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZapToCharUsage

misc.el is a small file (200 lines), so shouldn't hinder startup time very much, or you could copy the zap-up-to-char definition to your .emacs - see (find-function 'zap-up-to-char) after requiring misc.

Comment: Thank you. If I want both of these commands, any recommendation for the key binding?

Comment: @Nick M-Z is available - easy to remember, and only slightly awkward to type :)

Comment: That's easy to remember. Thank you!

Comment: A limitation is that it is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

This has been addressed in emacswiki:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZapUpToChar